# HTML form with 2 IMAGE submit buttons

Tags: html, forms, button, submit

I have a html form and I want 2 buttons. When users click a button it will submit a value (like) when they click the other button it will submit another value (dislike).

I was able to achieve that with the following script:

```
<input type=”submit” name=”rating” value=”like” />
<input type=”submit” name=”rating” value=”dislike” />
```

Now what I want to do next is to replace the 2 default submit buttons (the grey boxes) by nice images. I am trying that:

```
<input type=”image” name=”rating” value=”like” src=”pic1.png” alt=”submit”   />
<input type=”image” name=”rating” value=”dislike” src=”pic2.png” alt=”submit” />
```

The problem is that the value I specified (like/dislike) is not submitted anymore... Is there a way around that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS

```css
input {
background-image: url('http://www.clker.com/cliparts/3/P/l/W/c/E/orange-rectangle-button-hi.png');
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" name="rating" value="like" />
<input type="submit" name="rating" value="dislike" />
```

Or you can include the syle inside the input:

```html
<input style="background-image: url('http://www.clker.com/cliparts/3/P/l/W/c/E/orange-rectangle-button-hi.png');" type="submit" name="rating" value="like" />
<input style="background-image: url('http://www.clker.com/cliparts/3/P/l/W/c/E/orange-rectangle-button-hi.png');" type="submit" name="rating" value="dislike" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try the second option. I knew it was an easy problem but my coding skills are somehow limited. Thanks again :D

Comment: @Guillaume You're welcome. If you have any other questions, let me know. If my answer covered your question, consider choosing it as an accepted answer.. Best